# Function definition cannot understand

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know some javascript function declarations. Like exression function, anonymous function, but I do not understand what kind of syntax of these two functions? Can anybody tell me what is the name of these two functions? I mean "manipulateData: function (input)" and "getDataById: function (id)".

Why return statement can have this syntax to return two functions? Why not return one function in one time instead of two functions?  It will be great if you can give me some reference documents? Thanks.

```
app.service('MyService', function ($http, $q, $angularCacheFactory) {
    var _dataCache = $angularCacheFactory('dataCache', { 
        maxAge: 3600000 // items expire after an hour
    });
    /**
     * @class MyService
     */
    return {
        manipulateData: function (input) {
            var output;
            // do something with the data
            return output;
        },

        getDataById: function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (_dataCache.get(id)) {
                deferred.resolve(_dataCache.get(id));
            } else {
                // Get the data from the server and populate cache
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Look at `{ maxAge: 3600000 }` just above it. Same concept.

Comment: Like javascript object definition?

Comment: Yes, the function is returning an object that has two properties. The values of the properties just happen to be functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are just anonymous functions that happen to be values in an object. Consider this:

```
var object = {
  add: function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  }
};

object.add(1, 2); // = 3
```

This is the same as:

```
function addFunction(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

var object = {
  add: addFunction
};

object.add(1, 2); // = 3
```

There's nothing special about these functions, as they're just normal properties of an object.

Comment: Useful addition being the _why_: I.e. it's done using an object to return a public interface for this service. `_dataCache` represents a private data store.

Comment: Any advantage to do so?

Comment: Theres not necessarily an advantage to doing things this way vs. another. Just a method the dev used to solve a problem at the moment.

Comment: @AngularJS It's because JS doesn't have a public/ private visibility mechanism. `function addFunction(x,y)..` is in the global scope and is always public. It might be something completely internal to your module so it doesn't need to "pollute" the global scope. Using objects helps declare a public interface to your module whilst keeping other things private.

Comment: I see. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a function in this case but an Object.

When you define a `service` in angularjs you have to provide its implementation in the callback (the second argument of `app.service`)
This callback has to return methods you want to make available to other parts of your application.

Then in a controller or in another service you will be able to write:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["MyService", function(MyService) {
  MyService.getDataById('an id');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular Service returns an instance of the service you bind to the app namespace, those functions in the `return` statement are public methods that can be worked with. Basically an Object that contains two methods `manipulateData`, and `getDataById`.

It's similar to this

```
function company() {
  let product; // This is private

  // Public Methods
  return {

    setLatestProduct: function(value) {
      product = value;
      console.log(product, ' set');
    },

    getLatestProduct: function() {
      return product;
    }
  }

}

const apple = company();
console.log(apple); // { setLatestProduct: function, getLatestProduct: function }
```